# Creating a Custom Unsubscribe Page in ExactTarget

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there a way to create a custom unsubscribe page within ExactTarget?

Comment: You can use the LogUnsubEvent.

Answer (score 3):

You use Smart Capture for that. This requires the use of landing pages or microsites, and for the advanced features you need to know your way in AMPscript. But to use the basic functionality you can do without knowledge of AMPscript. More information on Smart Capture [here](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/smart_capture/).

Comment: You can also create your own unsubscribe page however you want and have the point your unsubscribe link to this page